# Ionic/Android 'requestCredentials is not defined'

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm currently working on a hybrid web/mobile app utilizing ionic/angular on the frontend and a rails api on the backend. I set up authentication with `devise_token_auth` and `ng_token_auth` and all was well with normal auth. I also setup facebook/twitter/instagram oauth on the web side which was working smoothly. The problem comes when I run the app on a tablet.

The app utilizes `chromium/crosswalk` to open an inAppBrowser window then prompts a social media login. The authentication works properly, hits the api and authenticates, then redirects to `/api/auth/{provider}/callback`, hitting the [OmniauthCallbacksController](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb). Everything completes properly in the controller, authenticating the user and returns a 200. However, the app is hung on a blank page, forcing me to close the browser where I receive an auth error for canceling the login.

Here is the last bit of code in the `devise_token_auth` controller for the successful callback when using an inAppBroswer:

```
def render_data(message, data)
  @data = data.merge({
    message: message
  })
  render :layout => nil, :template => "devise_token_auth/omniauth_external_window"
end
```

I receive this error in the logcat of the device:

`[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: requestCredentials is not defined"`

I've traced this down to the handleLoadStop method in ng-token-auth's javascript:

```
handleLoadStop: function(authWindow) {
  _this = this;
  return authWindow.executeScript({
    code: 'requestCredentials()'
  }, function(response) {
    var data, ev;
    data = response[0];
    if (data) {
      ev = new Event('message');
      ev.data = data;
      _this.cancelOmniauthInAppBrowserListeners();
      $window.dispatchEvent(ev);
      _this.initDfd();
      return authWindow.close();
    }
  });
}
```

So `ng-token-auth` is looking for a requestCredentials script in the call back but the HTML of the callback page is empty. I've tried several different solutions to try and get the devise_token_auth callback template to render [[see template here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/views/devise_token_auth/omniauth_external_window.html.erb)] to no avail. Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: any luck with this issue ?

Comment: I was never able to work out a solution :(